# Can I obtain accurate time without connecting to the internet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, system

I am writing an authorization software that I hope can also obtain the accurate system time when users modify it (for example, if I change the system time to 2022 or 2024, the software will display it as 2023). Of course, this software can also be used without networking

I tried using the motherboard for a while, but it only obtained the factory time; This difference is significant

```
import clr

clr.AddReference("System.Management")
import System.Management


select_1 = "SELECT * FROM Win32_BIOS"
info = System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(select_1)
info_list = [strInfo_1.Properties for strInfo_1 in info.Get()]

ipconfig_list = {}

for info_array in info_list:
    for i in info_array:
        ipconfig_list[i.Name] = i.Value
print ipconfig_list
```

Comment: This does not look like [tag:c]

Comment: Yes, sorry, this is my first time posting. I hope it hasn't affected you

Comment: I have modified the label to make it more visible to more people

Comment: Is this even related to C? Remove the tag unless you can edit your question why C is relevant. Don't just randomly add a tag to be "more visible". Windows and Linux don't have a separate time variable, they just use whatever the system clock says, with a timezone offset for presentation. The most you can do is log the time every time your software runs and then check that log for discrepancy, or perhaps check logs generated by other apps or the OS itself.

Comment: @SouravGhosh it is [.Net related.](https://pypi.org/project/pythonnet)

Comment: You want the accurate current time but have no access to any source that can provide that information to you? Yeah, no, not possible. When you change the time on your OS you're basically changing the BIOS time so there's no point trying to look there.

Comment: Okay, I'll delete it now

Comment: So does it take networking to achieve this effect?

Comment: this look like python 2 (e.g. the `print` statement), not python3

Comment: In practice, yes. In theory GPS and cellular receivers can read the time signal passively without connecting to proper internet

Comment: I can get the factory information on the motherboard, isn't that okay? If the user's motherboard is very old, such as in 2017, then the software authorization is basically invalid, right?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the device you're running it on has the time, which virtually every digital device does, you won't need to be connected to the internet. Python's [time library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) should be able to get you the time in practically every format you could ever want.